# CSS front-end framework for Apps that doesn't rely on any JavaScript framework

Tags: framework, css

Frameworks like [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/), [Onsen](http://onsen.io/), [Ionic](http://www.ionicframework.com/), [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/) and [Framework 7](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/) have a huge number of components to build App interfaces, but they are tied with Javascript frameworks, like Angular.

Are there CSS front-end frameworks / UI Kits for Apps (or that also has components designed for mobile) that doesn't rely on any JavaScript framework, so I can choose which framework to use?

**For example:**

[Material Design Lite](http://www.getmdl.io/) is an implementation of Material Design components in vanilla CSS, JS, and HTML, but have a limited set of components at this time.